# How to assign a member function to a pointer to member function in C++

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, variable-assignment, pointer-to-member

I'm trying to assign a member function to a pointer to a member function in C++, but I am getting an error. I have code like this:

```
#ifndef MY_CLASS_H
#define MY_CLASS_H

class MyClass {
    MyClass* (MyClass::*memPtr_) (ParamType);
public:
    void myFunction();
    void myFunction2();
    void myFunction3();

    MyClass& foo(ParamType var);
    MyClass& bar(ParamType var);
    MyClass& fooBar(ParamType var);
    ...
};

#endif
```

and...

```
void MyClass::myFunction() {
    memPtr_ = &MyClass::foo;
```

...

```
void MyClass::myFunction2() {
    memPtr_ = &MyClass::bar;
```

...

```
void MyClass::myFunction3() {
    memPtr_ = &MyClass::fooBar;
```

...

And on the lines

```
memPtr_ = &MyClass::foo;
```

and

```
memPtr_ = &MyClass::bar;
```

and

```
memPtr_ = &MyClass::fooBar;
```

when I compile - I get the error:

```
"cannot convert 'MyClass& (MyClass::*)(ParamType)'
to MyClass* (MyClass::*)(ParamType)' in assignment."
```

I've searched - but I can't seem to find the solution to this problem - what is the correct syntax to assign a member function to the pointer to member function 'memPtr_'?

Comment: So what do you think `foo` and `bar` should return? A `MyClass&`, nothing (`void`) or something else? That seems to be the problem in your code.

Comment: The syntax is fine. The problem is that you've got mismatching types. The error message says your functions return `MyClass&` while `memPtr_` has `MyClass*` return type.

Comment: @Mats Petersson:
   Sorry, there were some errors in the sample code. Foo, bar, and foobar should have returned MyClass&.

Answer (score 2):

Jrok is correct, and I fixed the problem. I simply changed:

MyClass* (MyClass::*memPtr_) (ParamType);

to...

MyClass& (MyClass::*memPtr_) (ParamType);

Answer (score 0):

You don't take the address of a function name with no `()`, that's the pointer.